# Store Unique counter in column based on other column

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I have table with primary auto increment and i want another column to set unique counter considering other column as primary.

Here is table structure i have,

| primary_id | order_id |
| --- | --- |
| 567 | 200 |
| 568 | 200 |
| 569 | 200 |
| 570 | 201 |

And i want to add new column like this,

| primary_id | order_id | counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 567 | 200 | 1 |
| 568 | 200 | 2 |
| 569 | 200 | 3 |
| 570 | 201 | 1 |

so `counter` column always have unique counter and should be dependant on `order_id`.
What should be the best approach in mysql to achieve this?
Counter should always retain unique id even row is removed.

Comment: Use a *view* and implement the logic with a window function.